# Not able to override the form template in symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have the form collection and in my template i have this code

```
 {% for task in form.usertasks %}
                <tr>
                <td> {{ form_row(task.mainTask.name) }} </td>
                <td> {{ form_row(task.tasknote) }}</td>
                <tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

Now the ouput of above code is like this

```
<td>  <div>
      <label> name</label>
      <input value="MYTASK NAME">
      </div>
</td>

<td> <div>
     <label> tasknote</label>
     <input value="TASK NOTE">
     </div>
</td>
```

IS there any way that i can get the following codeas final result.

```
<td>  MYTASK NAME </td>

<td> <input value="TASK NOTE"></td>
```

I have tried many things but i am not able to override. i tried from [this link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html).

Comment: There is everything you need in that chapter

Comment: where in that it says that i can capture the value of text box not the all element

Answer (score 0):

Firsty You shoud remove task.mainTask.name from form builder and use entity.mainTask.name  for example to dislay the value.